# resque-web: NoMethodError at /failed undefined method `to_yaml'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

Resque-web is up and running but when trying to view the failed jobs I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError at /failed
undefined method `to_yaml' for 3:Fixnum
```

The stack trace points to a '`to_yaml`' call as mentioned in the error, it seems like resque-web is missing a requires.  Has anyone else had this problem or know how to solve it?

Note: I'm running this locally on a rails 4 app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the reason here: https://github.com/resque/resque/issues/1143  -- it boils down to a temporary bug that is fixed, but not released yet.  I fixed mine by adding

```
require 'yaml'
```

at the top of the server.rb file

note that the server.rb file on my machine was located at: 
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/resque-1.25.1/lib/resque/server.rb

your location may vary